# Как компилить файлы в директорию выше?

Tags: php, phpstorm, typescript

$FileDir$ и прочие из подсказки пробовал уже по всякому
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А пробовали `$Sourcepath$/../`?

Comment: Да пробовал создает файл в корне проекта

Comment: А чем тебе tsconfig.json не нравится? Там же можно указать относительный путь...